# Открыть фрагмент из Notification который создан из Push

Tags: android, kotlin

Использую AndroidX, NavController.

Условия, приложение выгружено из памяти, при этом приходит пуш уведомление с разными clickAction (в разные фрагменты нужно отправлять)

Знаю, что можно было бы для активити сделать так

```
<activity android:name="NotificationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NotificationView" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

И если придет Push с clickAction = NotificationView то система откроет мое активити.

Можно ли такое сделать с фрагментом? Может есть более современный подход через NavController?

Comment: Ну так вам все равно ж надо открыть активити. Без активити фрагмент не может жить